# Using Dispose() method with SQL-Server Compact Edition 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I'm using Microsoft's SQL-Server Compact Edition 3.5 in my C# application. The `SqlCeConnection` will be encapsulated by an own Connection class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

class Connection
{
    public Connection()
    {
        m_connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        m_connection.Open();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        m_connection.Close();
    }

    private SqlCeConnection m_connection;
}
```

So my Question is: *Do I have to call the Dispose() method of the SqlCeConnection instance or may implement the IDisposable interface in my class?*

Stefan

Comment: that class doesn't appear to add any value....(so presumably you have cut it down?)

Comment: @Mitch Yep, i've cu it to the necessary elements for the SQL-Server handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are using an object that is disposable, you have to make sure that you call its `Dispose` method when the resource is no longer needed. You have several choices: you could call `Dispose` in the `Close` method of your own class, or, even better you could implement `IDisposable`.

Implementing `IDisposable` is highly recommended whenever your class stores resources that need disposing. This will allow users of your class to use the `using` pattern or call `Dispose` themselves, ensuring that resources are always freed as soon as possible.

Take a look at [Implement IDisposable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure that i have to implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `using` statement as it automatically calls the Dispose() on the specified object.

Comment: That method does't apply to me, because i use the `Connection` instance not in a local context - it has to be a class encapsulation.